# Elasticsearch aggregations filtered result is not working properly

Tags: json, elasticsearch, aggregation

1. two sample documents

POST /aggstest/test/1

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "type": "book",
            "words": [
                {"word":"storm","count":277},
                {"word":"pooh","count":229}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "magazine",
            "words": [
                {"word":"vibe","count":100},
                {"word":"sunny","count":50}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

POST /aggstest/test/2

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "type": "book",
            "words": [
                {"word":"rain","count":160},
                {"word":"jurassic park","count":150}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "megazine",
            "words": [
                {"word":"tech","count":200},
                {"word":"homes","count":30}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. aggs query

GET /aggstest/test/_search

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "categories.type": "book"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "categories.words.word": "storm"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "categories.type": "book"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "book_category": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "categories.words.word",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "categories.type": "book"
    }
  }
}
```

3. result

   ```
   {  
      "took": 5,  
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
         "total": 5,
         "successful": 5,
         "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
         "total": 1,
         "max_score": 0,
         "hits": []
      },
      "aggregations": {
         "filtered": {
            "doc_count": 1,
            "book_category": {
               "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
               "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
               "buckets": [
                  {
                     "key": "pooh",
                     "doc_count": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "key": "storm",
                     "doc_count": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "key": "sunny",
                     "doc_count": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "key": "vibe",
                     "doc_count": 1
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
   ```

========================

Expected aggs result set should not include "sunny" and "vibe" because it's "magazine" type.

I used filter query and post_filter, but I couldn't get only "book" type aggs result.

Comment: Why do you filter inside the aggregations? Try `"aggs" : { "agg_name" : { "terms" : " { "field" : "categories.words.words" } } }`

Answer (score 1):

All the filters you apply (in-query and in-aggregation) still return the whole `categories` document. And this document, which contains all 4 words, is a scope for aggregation. Hence you always get all 4 buckets.
As far as I understand, some way to manipulate buckets on server-side would be introduced with [reducers](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8110) in version 2.0 of Elasticsearch.

What you may use now is changing the mapping so that `categories` is [nested object](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/mapping-nested-type.html). Hence you'll be able to query them independently and aggregate accordingly using nested aggregation. Changing object type to nested requires reindexing.

Also please note that [post-filters](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-request-post-filter.html) are not applied to aggregation whatsoever. They are used to filter the original query without affecting the aggregation when you need to aggregate on wider scope than returned hits.

And one more thing, if you already have filter in query there's no need to put it in aggregation, scope is already filtered.

Comment: H Tiurini.  I work with Youngjun Kim.  Thanks for the tips. We had all those filters in there because we were trying everything!  We don't want to use nested objects because this would create too many documents... ~3000 per 'top-level' document, so in the trillions.  Lucene has a per shard doc # limitation... I think 1.5billion.  Anyway, If this is the case, I think we'll put the categories in their own objects (only about 5 categories)... like instead of categories.type=book, just have a book object.  Would you agree that that's the way to go given the further information I've provided?